# jQuery validate plugin: valid remote call bypassess other invalid checks

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have one remote rule and some other basic required rules. Oddly if my remote rule passes, but some of the other rules fail, it will go ahead and submit the form. I've tried moving the remote rule to the back or front of the list to see if it made a difference, and it didn't. Has anyone encountered this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LU5sU/7/ ( to pass validation, enter test in the promo code box. )

```
$('#ticket-form').validate({
onfocusout: false,
onkeyup: false,
onclick: false,
rules: {
    code: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: "http://www.bobmurdoch.com/ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data: {
                action: "check_code",
                code: function () {
                    return $("#code").val();
                }                    
            }
        }
    },
    first_name: {
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        required: true
    },
    company: {
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        required: true
    },
    state: {
        required: true
    },
    zip: {
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    survey_question_1: {
        required: false
    }
},
messages: {
    code: {
        required: "Please enter a valid promo code",
        remote: "Please enter a valid promo code"
    },
    first_name: "Please enter a value for First Name",
    last_name: "Please enter a value for Last Name",
    company: "Please enter a value for Company",
    address: "Please enter a value for Address",
    city: "Please enter a value for City",
    state: "Please enter a value for State",
    zip: "Please enter a value for Zip/Postal Code",
    phone: "Please enter a value for Phone",
    email: {
        required: "Please enter a valid e-mail address",
        email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address"
    }
},
showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
    var errors = '';
    for (var i in errorList) {
        errors = errors + errorList[i].message + "\n"
    }
    if (errors != '') {
        alert(errors);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI:  The HTML used in your jsFiddle demo is invalid.  You have multiple mismatched and stray tags.  You also use `<font>` tags which have been deprecated long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Following [the online documentation for `remote:`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options), I removed `async: false,` from `remote:` and it seems to be working as expected.

**As per documentation:**

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $("#username").val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LU5sU/8/)

**Your modified code:**

```
    code: {
        required: true,
        remote: {
            url: "http://www.bobmurdoch.com/ajax.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                action: "check_code",
                code: function () {
                    return $("#code").val();
                }                    
            }
        }
    },
```

---

**EDIT based on OP's comments:**

By removing your custom function for placing error messages inside the popup and using the default `errorPlacement:` function, I can show that this is working.  The input is showing `.invalid` class when invalid and `.valid` class when valid.  Your problem is elsewhere and has nothing to do with my solution.

See Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/LU5sU/11/

Comment: That gives weird results (I'll read up on the doc link you provided).  Now I get the error message but the input box is styled as valid.

Comment: @Steve, But your original jsFiddle shows no style changes at all for valid/invalid.  How could I see this with an incomplete demo?  AFAIK, this is solved... now the form will only pass validation if all required fields are properly filled out.